# Migration JDK8 to JDK11 : java.lang.ClassCastException [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Tags: java, java-8, migration, java-11

I have a very strange result with a ClassCastException in JDK11 on a specific JDK8 code.

```
private String[] schemasLocal;

@Before
public void init() {
    schemasLocal = (String[]) Arrays.asList("999").toArray();
}
```

It works perfectly with JDK8.
I know that this code is very ugly (I'm taking over an old application which is 6 years old), I know how to change it but I would like to understand the reason for the error between JDK8 and 11. (i use jdk8 from openJDK and now jdk11 from Azul openJFX)

In JDK11 I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at fr.cnamts.cpam.bordeaux.sages2.data.repositories.commons.migrations.MigrationBeanTest.init(MigrationBeanTest.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: See [JDK-6260652](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6260652) for the reason behind this.

Comment: Use `toArray(new String[0])` or `toArray(String[]::new)` instead of `toArray()` (doing so should also make the cast unnecessary). Or you could just use `new String[] {"999"}` instead of going from an implicit array, to a collection, back to an array.

Comment: Thx Johannes Kuhn. Perfect Explanation.
Thx Slaw, i know :)